# get the last inserted value of specific constraint

Tags: php, mysql

I need to fetch last inserted value for the m_id=2. I have two records for m_id=2 which has Id as its primary key I need to get `max(id)` for `m_id=2`

eg

id  m_id   MName

2   2       sample

3   2       sample1

I need to fetch only records of `Id=3`.I need to check for MAX(id) for below query

```
select a.*,b.MName,b.ZipCode,b.City,b.Address,b.email from insurance_details as a,insmemberdetails as b where b.id='2' and a.m_id='2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a ORDER BY id DESC and LIMIT 1:

```
select a.*,b.MName,b.ZipCode,b.City,b.Address,b.email 
from insurance_details as a,insmemberdetails as b 
where b.id='2' and a.m_id='2'
order by b.id desc 
limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it Like this:

```
select a.*,b.MName,b.ZipCode,b.City,b.Address,b.email 
from insurance_details as a,insmemberdetails as b 
where a.m_id='2' order by b.id desc limit 1
```

You Can also use it like this:

```
select a.*,b.MName,b.ZipCode,b.City,b.Address,b.email 
from insurance_details as a,insmemberdetails as b 
where b.id= (SELECT MAX(id) FROM b) and a.m_id='2'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:-

```
select a.*,b.MName,b.ZipCode,b.City,b.Address,b.email 
from insurance_details as a,insmemberdetails as b 
where b.id='2' and 
m_id = (SELECT MAX(m_id) FROM insurance_details)
```

Hope it will help you :-)